# Colors for C# collapsed region in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, colors, visual-studio-2012

I´m using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate version 11.0.51106.01 Update 1. 
I configured black as background color and white as foreground color but C# collapsed regions are appearing with a black foreground, making it invisible. How can I correct this?

Expanded regions with the correct colors:

[image: expanded region]

When collapsed, the region becomes invisible (black foreground and black background):

[image: collapsed region]

Comment: Set the colors of display item "Collapsed text (Collapsed)"

Comment: Have you seen this collection of VS color schemes? http://studiostyl.es/ It might be easier to use existing theme than create your own.

Comment: I tried to set foreground color of "Collapsed text (Collapsed)" to white but the result is the same, collapsed regions with black foreground. I already tried to set colors for several items, but no luck.

Comment: It seems to be a vs 2012 issue, the "Collapsed text(Collapsed)" option works in vs 2010, but not in vs 2012. The studiostle.es is nice, but when settings are imported in vs 2012 the problem remains

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem.  I found that "Collapsed text (Collapsed)" does indeed work.  The trick is that you have to *restart* Visual Studio for the changes to be applied.  I'm not sure why this is the case (since all other color changes happen immediately), but I've verified it by changing it a couple of times.

I've tested it using both the built-in UI, as well as the [Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05) extension.  Both cases require a restart (though I can't be sure if merely having the extension installed is causing it to behave poorly).

Comment: Ugh.  I really hate Visual Studio sometimes.  I've been messing with this for hours, thinking it was Resharper misbehaving and overriding my settings without telling me like it likes to do or that I was changing the wrong colors in the Environment options.  Nope, just good ol' Microsoft bugginess.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to restart VS, just create a custom color for the "Collapsed text (Collapsed)" as described by ijprest. This works for VS 2015. However, if you select one of the preset colors, you still have to restart VS.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work for me in VS 2015 - I used a custom color, but still had to restart.